# is it possible to use ms loop back adapter to setup local vlan

Tags: windows-7, vlan, local-area-network, tcpip, loopback

Is it possible to use Microsoft Loop back adapter to set up Lan connection between two computer which is logically isolated from the main network?

1st computer:
has a regular ip stack
192.168.1.x
255.255.255.0
192.168.1.1

192.168.1.1
8.8.8.8

Microsoft loop back adapter 
10.10.10.10
255.255.255.0
no gateway

no dns

2nd computer
10.10.10.11
255.255.255.0

both Connected to the same physical switch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loopback adapter shows up as another interface and as such traffic on it will kind of egress into neverneverland. This is not necessary. If you want the two hosts to only talk to each other, just add a second IP address with a different subnet scheme to the existing adapter, and leave the default gateway field blank.

Now if you needed to segment that traffic out so something else wouldn't even be able to sniff it, you could do some VLAN work, but I suspect this is more than you need.

Lastly, you could install a second NIC in each server and run a cable between them.